# How do i center two divs vertically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code snippet:

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('DIV');
wrapper.setAttribute("width", x * rows);
wrapper.setAttribute("height", y * columns);
wrapper.align = "center";

var buttonWrap = document.createElement('DIV');
buttonWrap.setAttribute("style", "clear:float");
```

As you can see in my code snippet, I have tried to center my div. But this code doesn't work. What works is making both divs fixed. But at the end of the day, the second div will then be upon the first div.

Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't do this using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use only **CSS** I would do it this way:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  
  /* Align center */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.small {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
.big {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="small"></div>
  <div class="big"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to do it in **javascript**, apply the style written above in CSS this way:

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
container.style.display = "flex";
```

and so on...